# Bijection of the function f: G→G

Tags: functions

Let G be a group, let the function f: G → G be defined by f(x)=x<sup>−1</sup>, and I want to prove that f is a bijection from G → G

So far i have surjection as 
Let f(a)=f(b) then a<sup>−1</sup>=b<sup>−1</sup>

→ a<sup>−1</sup>b = a<sup>−1</sup>*b= e (identity)

→ a<sup>−1</sup>*b= e

→ a<sup>−1</sup>=b<sup>−1</sup> → f(a)=f(b)

Therefore G is injective

So that for the function f: G→G to be surjective then

let y ∈ G , then let x ∈ G such that f(x)=y

(help needed)

Therefore G is surjective

I am also a little stuck trying to figure out what f<sup>−1</sup> is, any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: this has nothing to do with the group structure. The identity function $f(x)=x$ is a bijection on any set $X$. (Hint: what is its inverse?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surjectivity: Let $y \in G$. Define $x := y^{-1}$. Then $f(x) = f(y^{-1}) = (y^{-1})^{-1} = y$, so you found a preimage of $y$, thus $f$ is surjective.

Comment: How would I define x=y^-1? just state it as such?

Answer (score 2):

The other answer addresses surjectivity fine, but I wanted to point out that your proof of injectivity is incorrect. You started out correctly, but in the end all you proved is $f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow f(a)=f(b)$, a tautology. You need to prove $f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow a = b.$ Here's a possible proof:

Let $a^{-1} = b^{-1}$.

Then consider $aa^{-1}b = (aa^{-1})b=eb=b$.

However, because $a^{-1} = b^{-1}$, we have $aa^{-1}b = ab^{-1}b= a(b^{-1}b) = ae =a.$

So we have $a = ab^{-1}b = aa^{-1}b =b$, or $a=b$ as desired.

Comment: Also, I can't comment on the actual question because of low rep, but I think Ittaly Weiss's comment is misleading. The function you're looking at only makes sense if G has a group structure. I think he mis-read your question as asking about f(x) = x

Comment: In the first version of the post, user143325 had written $f(x)=x$. It was changed in an edit.

Comment: ok, i figured something like that had happened